# Custom Products Engine 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to generate a custom engine like products which
are categorized in Brands and Categories:

Products:

- Category 1

-----Product 1 /the same product in brand 1/

-----Product 2

-- Category 2

-- Category 3

Brands:

- Brand 1

-----Product 1 /the same product in category 1/

-----Product 2

- Brand 2
- Brand 3

What are the best scenarios to the above.

I did the following to achieve my needs:

1- Generated a new engine called category

```
$ rails generate refinery_engine category name:string image:image
$ bundle install
$ rails generate refinerycms_categories
```

2- Generated another engine called brand

```
$ rails generate refinery_engine brand name:string image:image
$ bundle install
$ rails generate refinerycms_brands
$ rake db:migrate
```

3- Generated an third engine called product and genreated that inside
category and brand engines:

```
$ rails generate refinery_engine product category:engine brand:engine
name:string category_id:integer brand_id:integer number:string
quantity:integer brief:string description:text image:image
catalog:resource
$ bundle install
$ rails generate refinerycms_categories products
$ rake db:migrate
```

4- I've edited the following files inside /vendor/engines/categories/
app/models:

category.rb

```
has_many :products
```

product.rb

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :brand
```

5- Also I've edited /vendor/engines/brands/app/models/brand.rb:

```
has_many :products
```

6- I've edited In _form.html.erb :category_id and :brand_id to make an
HTML  tag:

```
<div class='field'>
<%= f.label :category_id -%>
<%= collection_select(:product, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
</div>

<div class='field'>
<%= f.label :brand_id -%>
<%= collection_select(:product, :brand_id, Brand.all, :id, :name)%>
</div>
```

7-In the front-end product section I see all the products when I click
on a product Category and Brand are showing ids not the names. I need
to display names rather than ids.

8- When I click on categories it lists only categories without showing
the products inside it.... The same applies for brands. So how can I
list the products which are associated with categories and brands
inside each of them..

Thank you in advance for your support guys... I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a separate category and brands model doesn't make much sense to me. I would rather have them as fields in the product table and write a helper to get all unique categories and brands.
eg:

```
def get_categories
  Product.pluck(:category).uniq
end
```

To filter products by categories: (this would replace the select tag for categories in your _form.html.erb)

```
options_for_select(get_categories)
```

To select products belonging to the same category, you can do something like:

```
@products = Product.where("category=?",params[:category])
```